# wsimport : Service Interface with bean as method parameter

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

WSimport(http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL)  is creating All the source files. But the service interface(GlobalWeatherSoap) doesn't have methods to accept the bean Arguments.

```
/**
 * Get all major cities by country name(full / part).
 * 
 * @param countryName
 * @return
 *     returns java.lang.String
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetCitiesByCountry", action = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry")
@WebResult(name = "GetCitiesByCountryResult", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "GetCitiesByCountry", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET", className = "com.x.test.GetCitiesByCountry")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetCitiesByCountryResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET", className = "com.x.test.GetCitiesByCountryResponse")  
public String getCitiesByCountry(@WebParam(name = "CountryName", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET")
    String countryName);
```

I want to create the service interface methods which takes the bean as argument(GetCitiesByCountry). Could any one please help me with this.

Comment: You mean you want `getCitiesByCountry` to accept a single type `GetCitiesByCountryRequest`?

Comment: Yes kolossus.  method getCitiesByCountry() should accept a single type GetCitiesByCountryRequest